# Switching between Anaconda and regular python on windows

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

Some of my end-users are running simple Python 3 scripts,
I'm about to release to them a complex script which requires Anaconda installation (needs SciPy, numpy) and want them to be able to work with old scripts with no problem.

How can i switch between standard Python 3.4 to Anaconda from command line?

Comment: I think you should have to read about virtualenv, it create different environment for different packages/python version, then you can easily switch

Comment: Thanks, setting virtualenv to use Anaconda interpreter still doesn't use Anaconda packages (numpy for example). installing with conda package manager inside the virtual env folder didn't work. only installing with pip worked, but it's not possible to install numpy with pip easily. any ideas?